# Entropy for an open system?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

The Clausius theorem is a theorem that is important in thermal physics, for it makes it possible for us to define the state function entropy. My book derives the Clausius theorem with the assumption that the system is closed (ie. a system which doesn't exchange particles with the surroundings). I was wondering whether the Clausius theorem still applies for an open system (ie. one that exchanges particles with the surroundings). If not, then how does that influence the definition of entropy for an open system?

Comment: @Thormund The thermodynamic potentials I'm aware of are internal energy, enthalpy, Helmholtz free energy and Gibbs free energy. This is the first time I've heard entropy called a thermodynamic potential

Comment: @Thormund I am sorry, but I didn't quite understand your point. Surely it makes sense to talk about how the entropy is defined for an open system, and whether the Clausius theorem still applies or not?

Answer (score 0):

Clausius theorem applies for both open and closed systems. From the point of view of thermodynamics number of particles and chemical potential are a pair of conjugate quantities like any other, so the proof of Clausius theorem in this case looks essentially the same as for the case of a magnetic system or a system with a surface area and surface tension; there is an extra degree of freedom which has the potential for a little more book keeping, but nothing essential changes. You just replace the pressure/volume pair with a collection of all the degrees of freedom that do reversible work (i.e. all of them except the temperature/entropy pair).

Comment: Could you elaborate on what kind of proof you're referring to? I don't think this is the way I've seen it being proved, as the kind of proof that I've seen doesn't refer to the form of the work applied (whether it's magnetic, surface tension etc.). I'd really love a full derivation, if you don't mind.

Comment: That is really point. The type of work does not matter and since changing particle number is essentially just another type of work it does not matter if the system is open or closed. I did not have a particular proof in mind but was trying to guess what the proof you were looking at said that made the assumption of a closed system look essential

Comment: Okay, that's fair. But the proof I've seen involves Kelvin's statement of the second law of thermodynamics, which states that no process can occur whose sole result is the complete conversion of heat into work. Are you implying that the extra energy flux associated with a variable particle number (chemical potential times change in particle number) is a kind of "work" in the context of Kelvin's statement? If thst's the case, then yes, proving Clausius' theorem for open systems is easy, as the proof would actually be equivalent.